# Put a parameter in url using Easy Breadcrumb module

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I've a couple of url who use an id in it, I would like to set a custom breadcrumb for them but I can't arrive how to do it.
I tried using * or [0-9] in Paths to replace with custom breadcrumbs but it doesn't do anything.

For example for the url : /fr/checkout/11/order_information
I would like something as : /fr/checkout/*/order_information

Yet I don't know if that is possible, or maybe I'm not looking at the good section ?
Thank you for helping

Comment: I think custom_breadcrumbs module has that feature. Easy Breadcrumb has it for D8 version only. Give custom_breadcrumbs a try

Comment: @Ziftman unfortunately I'm on D8 and custom_breadcrumbs does not have a version for D8

Comment: If you using D8 then there is a patch might fit see https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb/issues/3051106